# Grouping data in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a python dataframe with a few columns, let's say that it looks like this:

| Heading 1 | Values |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| A | 2 |
| B | 9 |
| B | 8 |
| B | 6 |

What I want to is to "pivot" or group the table so it would look something like:

| Heading 1 | Value 1 | Value 2 | Value 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 2 |  |
| B | 9 | 8 | 6 |

I was trying to group the table or pivot/unpivot it by several ways, but i cannot figure out how to do it properly.

Comment: So if you 1000 Bs you are going to get 1000 columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can derive a new column that will hold a row number (so to speak) for each partition of `heading 1`.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"heading 1":['A','A','B','B','B'], "Values":[1,2,9,8,6]})
df['rn'] = df.groupby(['heading 1']).cumcount() + 1


     heading 1  Values  rn
0         A       1   1
1         A       2   2
2         B       9   1
3         B       8   2
4         B       6   3
```

Then you can pivot, using the newly derived column as your `columns` argument:

```
df = df.pivot(index='heading 1', columns='rn', values='Values').reset_index()

rn heading 1    1    2    3
0          A  1.0  2.0  NaN
1          B  9.0  8.0  6.0
```